# Spring data r2dbc: Problem connecting with mysql - 'r2dbcEntityTemplate' could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

My spring boot application is trying to connect to a `mysql` 5.7 with spring data r2dbc. The setup appears to be pretty straight-forward. However, I kept encountering unexpected exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

Logs:

```
2021-09-28 10:13:48.591  INFO 12261 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data R2DBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-28 10:13:48.651  INFO 12261 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 52 ms. Found 1 R2DBC repository interfaces.
//...
2021-09-28 10:13:49.250  WARN 12261 --- [  restartedMain] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
//...
Error creating bean with name 'healthCheckRepository' defined in application.model.respository.r2dbc.HealthCheckRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on MainApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'r2dbcEntityTemplate' while setting bean property 'entityOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'r2dbcEntityTemplate' available
//... 
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in application.service.HealthCheckService required a bean named 'r2dbcEntityTemplate' that could not be found. 


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'r2dbcEntityTemplate' in your configuration.
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:pool:mysql//server/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&useLocalSessionState=true
    username: username
    password: password
    pool:
      enabled: true
      max-size: 20
      validation-query: SELECT 1
      initial-size: 5
      max-idle-time: 30m
  data:
    r2dbc:
      repositories:
        enabled: true
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.2.0" //using
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'

//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    runtimeOnly 'dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql:0.8.2.RELEASE'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
}
```

Comment: why dont you use com.mysql.jdbc.Driver instead of r2dbc?

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuyền I need a reactive driver for potential high-load environment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655291/missing-databaseclient-in-postgres-spring-boot-r2dbc-application. This might help you !

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuyền Thanks for the attempt. Unfortunately, it doesn't really help, as I am defining the connection configuration in `application.yaml` instead of creating a `ConnectionFactory` and `DataClient` in code (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/143)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a Spring boot issue. Please refer to the below git issue for the resolution

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/659